# Definition of t-string basis in Linear Algebra by Jim Hefferon

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't understand the material on pages 415 - 418 of Linear Algebra (http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/book.pdf).  Is there an unstated constraint on what constitutes a t-string basis along the lines of "any t-string in a t-string basis must start with a basis vector and be of the maximum possible t-string length that does not end with zero for that starting vector".  Without some such constraint my mind gets confused. For example why isn't the sequence  for the example at the top of page 416 not a valid t-string basis?  It consists of the t-strings , ,  and .

Comment: Ignore the last two sentences of the post above. They don't make sense. What I meant to write was:  For example why isn't the basis e1, e3, e2, e4, and e5 a valid t-string basis for the example at the top of page 416?  This t-string basis consists of the following t-stings: e1-e3, e2, e4-e5.

Answer (score 1):

> A $t$-string basis is a basis that is a concatenation of $t$-strings.

Every element of a basis is certainly a basis vector, hence *every* element of these $t$-strings must be. There’s no hidden or unstated constraint here in that regard.

On the other hand, there does appear to be a tacit assumption that the strings in a $t$-string basis are maximal. This follows somewhat from the preceding material that describes the action of $t$ in terms of “null-terminated” strings, but it should’ve been made explicit in the definition, since the immediately following example illustrates that $t$-strings in general don’t have these additional constraints.

The ultimate goal is to decompose $V$ into a direct sum of $t$-invariant subspaces generated by these strings. If you truncate a string that would otherwise have had additional linearly-independent vectors in it, the generated subspace will not be $t$-invariant, hence the tacit maximal-length requirement.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I'll trudge forward with the assumption that I'm dealing with maximal t-strings.